# Почему не растягиваются контейнеры после установки бутстрапа?

Tags: css, bootstrap, nextjs

Установил бутстрап и не пойму, почему не растягиваются контейнеры. При установке nextjs была такая же проблема и решилась удалением параметра:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

А после установки бутстрапа проблема вернулась и не решается зачисткой этого параметра в модулях:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть еще причина?

Как должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как стало:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это бред, но бутстрапу оказывается не катят прежние размеры контейнера и надо их расширить в 2 раза. Не знаю насколько уместно тут вставлять код, но пусть будет:

```css
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
```